# Javascript prototype property descriptor

Tags: javascript

Can someone elucidate me? Should the following not be a property descriptor?

```js
const A = (function() {
  function A(value) {
    this._value = value;
  };

  A.prototype.value = {
    get function() {return this._value},
    set function(value) {
      console.log(this._value);
      this._value = value;
    },
  };

  return A;
})();

var a = new A('test');

console.log(a.value);
// {
//     function:undefined
// }
```

How is this supposed to work?

*I'm very new to this language.*

Comment: line 10: `this._value = v;` should be `this._value = value;` ? ... but of course this is not the only reason for the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Yes. It should. Makes no difference. Was just a typo from changing the var names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation was to shift the getter/setter implementation from the prototype to the constructor either as function with `this` context or as part of a real class.

With the following implementation one ...

1. ... keeps the OP's low level constructor approach.
2. ... keeps the getter and setter and ...
3. ... is not forced to compromise the already naturally provided encapsulation.

```js
function A(value) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'value', {
    get: function () {
      return value;
    },
    set: function (val) {
      return (value = val);
    },
    enumerable: true
  });
}
const a = new A("test");

console.log(
  'Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(a) => ',
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(a)
);
console.log('Object.keys(a) => ', Object.keys(a));

console.log('a.value : ', a.value);

console.log('a.value = "foo" : ', (a.value = "foo"));
console.log('a.value : ', a.value);

console.log('a.value = 42 : ', (a.value = 42));
console.log('a.value : ', a.value);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to declare a class, why not just use `class`?

```js
class A {
  constructor(value) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  get value() { return this._value }
  set value(v) {
    console.log(this._value);
    this._value = v;
  }
}

var a = new A('test');

console.log(a.value);
```

If you want to avoid the `class` syntax, then I'd go with `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
function A(value) {
  this._value = value;
}

Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'value', {
  get: function () {
    return this._value
  },
  set: function (v) {
    console.log(this._value)
    this._value = v
  }
});

var a = new A('test');
console.log(a.value);
a.value = 'test2'
console.log(a.value);
```

Comment: Is that not just syntactic sugar, as they call it? Appreciate the suggestion, but that does really address the question. With my lack of knowledge of this language, and from experience in trying to grasp what the hell is going on here, `class` hinders the learning development. Feel free to disagree, that is just my stance atm, ever changing. We avoid magical numbers all the time, having more magic rarely helps discovering.

Comment: I meant: does **not** address the question.

Comment: Sure... but the modern syntax exists for just this purpose, to make it easier to do these things (and to read the code in which these things are done). Your own answer has it where you are replacing the object's prototype with an entirely new object, which might work here, but seems relatively clunky to me. I'd be wary of that.

Comment: Ok. Can you address my answer then? What would be a correct approach to that?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues classes in js are not just syntactic suggar. [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), soon [decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), [extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends), [and alot more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). they also have performance benefits. i don't want to dig out the corresponding [v8](https://v8.dev/) sourcecode to proof that though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```js
const A = (function() {
  function A(value) {
    this._value = value;
  };

  A.prototype = {
    get value() {return this._value},
    set value(value) {
      console.log(this._value);
      this._value = value;
    },
  };

  return A;
})();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity ... is the chosen design from above due to learning / research / exploration or is something similar going to be the base of production code?

Comment: @PeterSeliger All of them. At the moment is very much a learning phase. Feel free to post an answer to elaborate your question, very welcome.

Comment: @PeterSeliger The choosen design has a very important consideration, the API works and I can read it.

Comment: My concerns are about the public accessibility of `_value` which is *private* by convention. The getter/setter approach via prototype keeps an `A` instance lean and clean. But all of e.g. a setters additional guarding/observing code is obsolete as long as `_value` remains exposed. From my experience encapsulation/visibility matters. Over the course of time, with growing complexity, with a shifting developer base, etc the chances of an uncontrolled direct access will raise exponentially. What is exposed into public will be accessed sooner or later.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Understood. Not really an issue in my case. Coming from a python background that is very common. Getting back to my previous argument. The most important part in all is readability, it is imperative all devs have a correct interpretation of what the code is doing. Dunder attributes are private by convention in python.

Comment: Do you ever need to iterate over such an object?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Uhm. Not now, no. But I will be curious as to why your question. But no. We may iterate some attribute, but not the object itself.